# why does my program hang when I use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

There is a simple communication program that I used in MPICH2. when I execute the program by using

```
mpiexec.exe -hosts 2 o00 o01  -noprompt mesajlasma.exe
```

The program starts but does not end. I can see it is still running on the host computer "o01" by using resource monitor program. When I press <kbd>CTRL + c</kbd>, it is ended. Then I can see that my program ran properly

Why doesn't my program end. Where does it stuck? why does my program hang when I use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv?

Thanks in advance

```c
// mesajlasma.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int  nTasks, rank;
    char mesaj[20];
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nTasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    //printf ("\nNumber of threads = %d, My rank = %d\n", nTasks, rank);

    if(rank == 1)
    {
        strcpy_s(mesaj, "Hello World");
        if (MPI_SUCCESS==MPI_Send(mesaj, strlen(mesaj)+1, MPI_CHAR, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD)) printf("_OK!_\n");
    }


    if(rank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Recv(mesaj, 20, MPI_CHAR, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Received Message:%s\n", mesaj);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your MPI library? Is it openmpi or MPICH or MPICH2? What is an exact version? Unix or Windows?

Comment: My library is MPICH2. In both computers, windows 7 is the operating system. Actually there are 41 computers which I installed MPICH2 and they work properly for simple &laquo;hello world&raquo; applications. But if I use MPI_Send and MPI_Receive functions, then it hangs. Therefore, I simplyfied the problem to two computers (o00 and o01) and wrote on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need to pass an argument like `-n 2` to your `mpiexec.exe` command in order to instruct it to launch 2 processes.  I believe that the `-hosts` argument is just an alternative way to specify the hosts on which your program can run, not how many processes will be created.

Comment: I tried to run with `-n 2` and I got the host names from a **host_list.txt** by using `-machinefile`. But still it works good for a host (even a remote one) but it doesn't work for two hosts till I press `ctrl+c`

Comment: Hmm... sounds like a networking problem to me.  I would recommend contacting the full MPICH2 development team at `mpich-discuss@mcs.anl.gov`.  Since you are on Windows you have exceeded my ability to troubleshoot this issue.  If/when you get the problem sorted out, make sure to post the solution back here at SO.